# Automaping a JSON array to a list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, odata, automapper

I want to parse a JSON that comes with a request to my OData v4 service into a DTO and afterwards project this DTO to the EF Model class and vice versa. The JSON includes a few flat fields and an array. While processing of the EF model object is done automatically by EF, i want to manually take care of the left overs of the DTO object in the controller and save them by using my own reposity class.

Is it possible to parse the request using AutoMapper to the DTO and afterwards simply skip the list while projecting to the EF class object and if so, how?

The JSON

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:30955/$metadata#Customer/$entity",
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Number": "1",
    "CreatedByUserId": 1,
    "ModifiedByUserId": 1,
    "CustomerCustomFields": [
        { "CF_Test": "foo", "CF_Test2": "foobar"},
        { "CF_Test": "foo2", "CF_Test2": "foobar2"}
    ]
}
```

My DTO class and sub class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class CustomerDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
        public int? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CustomerCustomField> CustomerCustomFields { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace API.Models
{
    public class CustomerCustomField
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My EF model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace API.Models
{  
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer() {}

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? DeletedOn { get; set; }
        public int? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use JSON.Net to parse JSON into your models, then map via Automapper.

Comment: "Is it possible to parse the request using AutoMapper to the DTO". This is what a JSON deserialiser (such as JSON.NET) does. AutoMapper transforms .NET objects into other .NET objects. So once you've got your DTO as a result of the binder deserialising the JSON, then you'd map from your DTO to the EF object using AutoMapper.

Comment: Shouldn't the default OData deserializer automatically transform the array into a list?

Comment: can you show how you receive the JSON data into your application?

Comment: Im pretty new to Odata and thus trying to figure out how to achieve as we speak pretty much

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was actually really simple. I simply mixed up the property names of the CustomerCustomFields-class with the actual names of the custom fields. Changing the property names to `Name` and `Value` solved this for me as the included serializer is able to transform the list of custom fields to a list in my DTO class.

Answer (score 0):

Be close to EF model. 
There is nothing bad with this:

1. from web client pass JSON data in the structure that can be deserialized to entity class (even if you send not all fields)
2. deserialize it with JSON.NET to you entity (entity + dependencies)
3. load entity (as tracked) from storage by its id
4. copy deserialized entity fields to the tracked entity
5. save dbcontext.

Step 3) can be automatized with many "copy one object to another" tools (e.g. I list properties that need to be copied in the EFCore:

```
        Include<TestModel> includes
            = chain => chain
                .Include(i => i.Field1)
                .Include(i => i.Field2)
         ObjectExtensions.Copy(source, destination, includes);
```

What I want to say DTO is good when you are using it for "selfdescribed" services like wcf services, where there is such thing as XSD schema. Then creating DTO you also create documentation. But there are no "JSON schema" with web services, there are no such practice, so there are no strong reasons to use DTO.

Comment: The reason why i use a DTO is that i have kind of a dynamic database structure. While a part of it represents the EF Model, the fields of the custom fields can be changed at runtime (additional fields result in new columns in the db table) so i need to extract that from the EF Model. I wish i could use the EF for these aswell, but i have to do it manually. Parsing to DTO using the included OData parser already fulfill its job. Mapping with AutoMapper also works fine. Working with XSD's and XML's is also planned for the future. Sadly i can't change the database structure.

Comment: You can freely use your structures in web client, but when you send it to storage service: send them as storage require. Think about it as about "common sense convention" - transformations should be done on the clients to save remote server resources otherwise you should have a strong reason to do it on the remote server. Analogy that works: RDBMS updatable views and stored procedures - are very specialized tools and you should have strong reasons to prefer them instead of "simple" DML. With EF - it is the same situation: web api should follow the model.